# Set specific values for ray visibility on lights

Tags: lighting, volumetrics, visibility

In other software (houdini, 3ds max) there is a way to set lights to have specific Ray multiplier values. For example having diffuse at 1.0 but volume scatter at 15.0. This would make its volume emission 15x more potent than its diffuse.

In blender at the moment I can only see a tickbox to either enable or disable specific rays.

If I want to have a really strong volumetric light that still casts some diffuse rays what do I do?